# How to get TableColumn by column name in existing JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to change header title of existing `JTable` by this method.

```
private JTable datatable;

public void ChangeTitleColumn(String ColumnName,String HeaderTitle){

    JTableHeader th = datatable.getTableHeader();
    TableColumnModel tcm = th.getColumnModel();     
    TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(0);   //<---- How to refer by ColumnName
    tc.setHeaderValue( HeaderTitle );
    th.repaint();
}
```

But `TableColumnModel` can refer by index of column only. How to get `TableColumn` by column name?

Comment: Please use common Java nomenclature. I.E. `ChangeTitleColumn` → `changeTitleColumn`, `ColumnName` → `columnName` & `HeaderTitle` → `headerTitle`.

Comment: `th.getTable().getColumn("identifier");`